# How to change iframe src using css

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to remove ads from my profile on a website, so I don't have access to the original css or code, but there is still the ability to change the css code by editing the profile.

For example I have added these lines:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.topad {display:none; visibility:hidden;}
#buyers_ad {display:none; visibility:hidden;}
</style>
```

which removes an advertisement from the top and right side of the page.

The problem is that there is an iframe that points to an advertisement. Is it possible to change the src that the iframe points to using css, but not html? The iframe does not have a class or id.

It's an iframe inside a div, if that is helpful.

Comment: Are there other iframes that you wish to keep? If not, maybe just add a rule to hide all iframes: `iframe {display:none; }`

Comment: I don't think there's a possible solution that will work with all modern browsers without Javascript. You can hide it with css, but src of iframe is not a css property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make iframe hidden using css

Html:

```
<div id="somediv">
<iframe .... />
</div>
```

css:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
#somediv > iframe { display : none}
</style>
```

**Or you can also change src of iframe using Jquery / JS**

Html:

```
<div id="somediv">
<iframe .... />
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#somediv iframe').attr('src','http://google.com');
```

Hope It Helps You.. :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm just wondering what the '>' sign does in the css example, between #somediv and iframe?

Comment: means #somediv 's child iframe..
See http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/ for more info

Comment: This is explained in that link ^ but note that the `>` selects direct children. For the html `<parent><iframe/><child><iframe/></child></parent>`, the css `parent iframe {display: none}` will hide both iframes, and `parent > iframe {display: none}` will not hide the iframe inside <child>.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery thats the better option to hide